# Java - How to save a .txt file where you want

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

I want the String `text` to be saved as a .txt file wherever I want. I think you can do that by using JFileChooser. Anyway here is my Code:

```
class TextEditorFrame extends JFrame {

    JFileChooser chooser;

    public TextEditorFrame(){

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        chooser = new JFileChooser();

        String text = s.nextLine();

        try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"))){
            out.print(text);
            System.out.println("Text Saved:");
            System.out.println(text);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong...");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code so far. Any way I can combine the JFileChooser with the String text?

NOTE: This is not the full code but everything you need to know is in here.

Comment: Have you looked at the API for JFileChooser?

Comment: Look up the JFileChooser in the API and also try a showDialog method, that way you can manually chose where you would like to save your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes the PrintStream go onto the selected file of the JFileChooser you have made.

```
File file = chooser.showSaveDialog();
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
```